# What hypothesis can be drawn from a dataset that looks like this?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, spss, ordinal-data, analytical

[image: This is an image of my dataset with three variables. I am new to working with SPSS; I want to know how to draw a hypothesis with such a dataset.]

Here is a picture of my dataset. I have three questions. 1) What are the dependent independent variables in this dataset? 2) How can I identify the year here as ordinal or nominal? 3) What possible hypothesis statements can be drawn out of such a dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got this backwards. You don't (typically) look at the data and come up with a hypothesis based on this. This is a recipe for [p-hacking](/questions/tagged/p-hacking) and unreliable inferences. Instead, you make your hypothesis first, and then evaluate it with the data.

That is a simplification, of course. You can do exploratory data analysis and use your data to *generate* hypotheses that can be tested on future datasets. Or if you have a large enough dataset, you can split it into two (randomly in the simplest case, but there are ways to do this if there is hierarchical structure in the data as well). You use one half to explore and generate hypotheses, and then test the hypotheses on the other half that you have not examined.

All this assumes you are using a Null Hypothesis Statistical Testing framework (which I assume based on your question). The general workflow would be different if you were using a Bayesian framework.

Comment: +1, mkt. We have been taught early about the "it's a trap" paradigm and the tendency to concoct the frame work of hypothesis after seeing the data - a recipe of data snooping.

Comment: You explained it very well @mkt. I am new to spss and this is my starting point. Can I use the correlation analysis technique on the provided dataset and then generate a hypothesis out of it? for example, if I study the strength of correlation of two variables (say dogbreed and year), can I come up with a hypothesis? could you  please simplify it for me

Comment: @QasimBashir Happy to help. This is not an SPSS issue or matter of trying a different technique, though, it's about conceptual understanding. I strongly recommend doing some reading to understand the concepts before proceeding. Any specific recommendations about techniques would not really help you if you're not clear about what exactly a hypothesis is, what it means to test it, and how to reliably draw inferences from data.

Comment: @QasimBashir, if you think mkt's post answered your query, kindly accept the answer by clicking the tick sign along the post.

Comment: My question is still if I can draw a hypothesis from the correlation analysis of 2 variables.

Comment: And after looking at the dataset. What possibly can be the dependent and independent variable as I wish to study bivariable correlation

Comment: @QasimBashir As I explained in my answer and comment above, I do not support this simple approach - it is very likely to lead to incorrect conclusions.

Comment: Qasim, in requesting that we identify the independent and dependent variables you are asking us to tell you why you are analyzing the data.  That's not something that can be determined from the data alone.  It's a little like telling us "42 is the answer.  What is the question?"